Dynamic MTD and YTD slicer using YTD Data
I have provided the image of the sample data where I have YTD data (Actual, Plan, Prior Year) by period for a city. I already have a slicer with periods.
Suppose I select Period 6 in the period slicer, I want a slicer to switch between MTD and YTD data for period 6.
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
